# Proving the quadrilaterals cyclic

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and let $D, E, F$ be the feet of the altitudes, on $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Let the parallel through $D$ to $EF$ meet $AB$ at $X$ and $AC$ at $Y$ . Let $T$ be the intersection of $EF$ with $BC$ and let $M$ be the midpoint of side $BC$. Prove that the points $T, M, X, Y$ are con-cyclic.

I am interested in the question above. I tried using power of points and the nine point circle. After a length bash, I concluded that its enough to show that $$\frac{BD}{BM}=\frac{TB}{TM}$$but I have no idea how to proceed further. Any progress will be highly appreciated.

P.S.: Any other approaches for proving the problem will also be entertained.

Comment: Theoretically you can apply lots of laws of sines and express all $BD, BM, TB, TM$ in terms of $AB, \sin \theta, \cos\theta$, where $\theta = A, B$ or $C$. I tried for a while and was able to do that, but it took me too long to compute the claim you are trying to show.

Comment: If there is a relatively simpler method than proving $$\frac{BD}{BM}=\frac{TB}{TM}$$please let me know.

Comment: By internal angle bisector theorem, we have TB : TD = TF : FD. By external angle bisector theorem, we have TF : FD = TC : CD. Also TM : BM = TM : MC = TM : ME = TM : MF but unfortunately no angle bisector found.

Comment: I think I have the solution for you but I am interested in why proving the said equality of ratios can lead to the required solution. Would you like to include that in your question?

Comment: @Mick Thanks for that! I have edited the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let P be the midpoint of FB. Extend MP to cut TF at Q.

After such construction, MBQF is a kite with $\angle DFB = \angle DFQ = \angle FBQ$ and $\angle BQM = \angle FQM$. The latter implies QM is the external angle bisector of $\angle BQF$ of $\triangle TQB$.

[image]

Draw QR // AB cutting TB at R. Since $\angle RQM = \angle BPM = 90^0$, QR is then the internal angle bisector of $\angle TQB$.

Therefore, $\dfrac {TM}{BM} = \dfrac {TR}{RB}$.

But, $\dfrac {TR}{RB}= \dfrac {TQ}{QF}$; because of similar triangles.

Further, $\dfrac {TQ}{QF} = \dfrac {TB}{BD}$; because of similar triangles.
.